# What permissions does a directory need so that anyone can cd into it but nobody but root can ls in it?

Tags: bash, unix, permissions

I have seen this before in some directories. Where if you know the name of a file you can open it and edit it, but you cannot `ls` in the directory so if you don't know the name of the file you can't really do anything with it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Execute permissions will allow traversal. No read permissions will prevent reading of the contents. Therefore, `-r+x`.